# Angular: $interval undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am getting error while trying to use `$interval`.

> Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $interval is not defined

Sample code in Plnkr: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xmpI2SwMN9pVccU5ufR7?p=preview)

Can someone please help me out. Thanks!

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

(function() {
  var MainController = function($scope, $http, $interval) {

    var OnSuccess = function(response) {
      $scope.user = response.data;
      $http.get($scope.user.repos_url).then(OnLoadRepos, OnError)
    };

    var OnLoadRepos = function(response) {
      $scope.repos = response.data;
    };
    var OnError = function(response) {
      $scope.user = "";
      $scope.error = "could not fetch the data.";
    };

    $scope.search = function(username) {
      $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username).then(OnSuccess, OnError);
    };
    $scope.message = "GitHub Viewer!";
    $scope.username = "angular";
    $scope.countdown = 5;
    $scope.repoSortOrder = "-stargazers_count";
  };
  var decrementCountDown = function() {
    $scope.countdown -= 1;
    if ($scope.countdown < -1) {
      $scope.search($scope.username);
    }
  };
  MyApp.controller('MainController', MainController);

  var startCountdown = function() {
    $interval(decrementCountDown, 1000,$scope.countdown);
  };
  startCountdown();
}());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're trying to access Angular specific services outside angular's scope.

From a quick view it seems that you want to start the countdown as soon as the file loads. Well, you can do so by including the code in the controller itself.

Your updated code looks like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/cXQlGr57RGmBJEagbvpR?p=preview) :

```
    var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

    (function() {
        var MainController = function($scope, $http, $interval) {

            $interval(decrementCountDown, 1000, $scope.countdown);

            var OnSuccess = function(response) {
                $scope.user = response.data;
                $http.get($scope.user.repos_url).then(OnLoadRepos, OnError)
            };

            var OnLoadRepos = function(response) {
                $scope.repos = response.data;
            };
            var OnError = function(response) {
                $scope.user = "";
                $scope.error = "could not fetch the data.";
            };

            $scope.search = function(username) {
                $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username).then(OnSuccess, OnError);
            };
            $scope.message = "GitHub Viewer!";
            $scope.username = "angular";
            $scope.countdown = 5;
            $scope.repoSortOrder = "-stargazers_count";

            var decrementCountDown = function() {
                $scope.countdown -= 1;
                if ($scope.countdown < -1) {
                    $scope.search($scope.username);
                }
            };
        };

        MyApp.controller('MainController', MainController);


    }());
```

Answer (score 4):

**Mistake** :

Here your `startCountdown` function is outside of angular's controller 
so it is simple javascript function.

In Javascript function you are using `$interval` dependency so it will not work.

**Solution**:

One more thing you have injected `$interval` in controller so by transferring your `startCountdown` functuion into the angular function in the controller will work.

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

(function() {
  var MainController = function($scope, $http, $interval) {

    var OnSuccess = function(response) {
      $scope.user = response.data;
      $http.get($scope.user.repos_url).then(OnLoadRepos, OnError)
    };

    var OnLoadRepos = function(response) {
      $scope.repos = response.data;
    };
    var OnError = function(response) {
      $scope.user = "";
      $scope.error = "could not fetch the data.";
    };

    $scope.search = function(username) {
      $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username).then(OnSuccess, OnError);
    };
    $scope.message = "GitHub Viewer!";
    $scope.username = "angular";
    $scope.countdown = 5;
    $scope.repoSortOrder = "-stargazers_count";
  };
  var decrementCountDown = function() {
    $scope.countdown -= 1;
    if ($scope.countdown < -1) {
      $scope.search($scope.username);
    }

    $scope.startCountdown = function() {
        $interval(decrementCountDown, 1000,$scope.countdown);
     };
     $scope.startCountdown();
  };
  MyApp.controller('MainController', MainController);

}());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your cannot access $interval outside the controller or angular's reach.

Try this

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

(function() {
  var MainController = function($scope, $http, $interval) {

    var OnSuccess = function(response) {
      $scope.user = response.data;
      $http.get($scope.user.repos_url).then(OnLoadRepos, OnError)
    };

    var OnLoadRepos = function(response) {
      $scope.repos = response.data;
    };
    var OnError = function(response) {
      $scope.user = "";
      $scope.error = "could not fetch the data.";
    };

    $scope.search = function(username) {
      $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username).then(OnSuccess, OnError);
    };
    $scope.message = "GitHub Viewer!";
    $scope.username = "angular";
    $scope.countdown = 5;
    $scope.repoSortOrder = "-stargazers_count";
    $scope.startCountdown = function() {
      $interval($scope.decrementCountDown, 1000,$scope.countdown);
    }
    $scope.decrementCountDown = function() {
      $scope.countdown -= 1;
      if ($scope.countdown < -1) {
        $scope.search($scope.username);
      }
    };
  };
  MyApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope','$http', '$interval', MainController]); //Dependency injection
}());
```

Also note the dependency injection which is a good practise.

I called the startCountDown during initialization.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">

<head>

   <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.13"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController" ng-init="startCountdown()">
  <h1>{{message}}</h1>
  <div>{{error}}</div>
{{countdown}}
<form name="searchUser" ng-submit="search(username)">
 <input type="search" required placeholder="UserName to find" ng-model="username"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
<div ng-include="'userdetails.html'" ng-show="user"></div>
</body>

</html>
```